# Updating the elements of an array(The oldest element will be deleted after a new element has entered to array)

Tags: c++

I have a question but I don't know how to search about it, so wanted to ask you.
It may sound simple but I'm a kind of a newbie.

I'm coding in C++. I have 20 values in an array. I do some work on them and after the calculation, I need to add a new value to these 20 values and need to delete the oldest variable. A kind of updating the array with new values.

For example: 
My previous values : a,b,c,d, .... t
My current values : b,c,d,e .... u

This process will go on under a loop as long as the condition is not satisfied.

So, my question is: Is there any specific structure or method to perform this task or do I have to handle this work manually ? (Actually, I could do it by writing an impractical method which could be enough for me but I don't think there might not be a dedicated stack structure for this work)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::queue` is designed for FIFO operations.

Comment: Agree use a `queue` it has the semantics you are after

Comment: "I do some work on them" -- Does this mean you need access to all elements?  In which case, you cannot use a queue (effectively), and your best option is `std::deque`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Yes I need to access to all elements at all time. For example, Everytime, I calculate the average of values and according to result, I will add a new value to the end of the stack and delete the oldest(first) one.

Comment: @Horizon1710: For that, you don't need access to all elements.  If you keep track of the sum of the elements, then when you remove the oldest element, you can subtract its value from the sum, and when you add a new element, you can add its value to the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::queue` or `std::deque`(difference that queue is FIFO(first in first out) when deque can remove elements from both sides):

```
if (queue.size() == MAX_SIZE) {
    queue.pop_front();
}
queue.push_back(value);
```

Comment: deque is heap-like?  What does that mean?

Comment: Updated my post. Sure queue implements FIFO concept when heap represens FILO concept.

Comment: That's a stack you're thinking of.  In a heap, objects come out based on their value, not the order they were inserted.

Comment: [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_data_structure) has other meanings. Plus, in C++ speak, `std::stack` provides FILO.

Comment: @DenisErmolin, I tried a simple example of your piece of code, it worked. looks it will work for my project too. Thanks!